# How to launch a remote process through ssh and end the connection?

Tags: ssh, display, nohup

This is still blocking:

```
ssh host nohup cmd
```

This still leaves the connection open:

```
ssh host nohup cmd &
```

Comment: Is there really no way to properly do this? I've been struggling all day, and none of the options seem to leave the remote process running AND terminate the local SSH process. The best I've got so far is to run the SSH in the background, wait 15 seconds, then kill the PID. But that's ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ssh host batch cmd
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, but note that `batch` depends on having a working `cron`/`at` system on the remote system.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` in your example will detach the ssh command, but not your remote program.

This seems to work:

<strike>ssh remote-host 'tail -f /var/log/syslog &' &</strike>

```
ssh remote-host 'tail -f /var/log/syslog > /dev/null &' &
```

The first `&` will detach the command for the remote host, and the second `&` will detach the ssh command itself

In my example, the tail command is still running after I've closed the connection.

---

**edit** this does not seems to work as `tail` exits shortly after the connection is actually closed.

This may be related to the fact that it's writing to `STDOUT` which will probably raise a broken pipe after the connection is closed

**edit 2** works fine when redirecting the tail command to /dev/null ^_^

Just be careful and don't write to stderr  / stdout, or redirect the output to a local destination

Answer (score 1):

This issue is apparently long standing (even longer than your question!). The solution is to redirect stdout and stderr. The text book example is this:

```
ssh server 'sleep 20 & exit'
```

which hangs for 20 seconds. Using bash you can rewrite it to:

```
ssh server 'sleep 20 >/dev/null 2>&1 & exit'
```

which fixes the issue. For tcsh you would use something along the lines of:

```
ssh server '(sleep 20 >/dev/null) >& /dev/null & exit'
```

**References**

- A bug report from 2001 https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52
- The original site I found discussing the solution above http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/users/3434

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
ssh myhost " nohup ./r.sh & " & sleep 2 ; kill -9 $! && echo
```

(at least if you are not prompted for a password).
In case you are I don't see a easy way to do it.